# C# serial port can not get all data from com port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hi i am using C# to get data from com port. With using Hercules to check data, see this image to compare config:

[image]

In Hescules data show with format: FF??ZZ, but in C#, date get only : FF

Here is C# code:

```
SerialPort _serialPort;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //ShowNetworkInterfaces();
            getDataFromComPort();
        }

        private void getDataFromComPort()
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

                _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                //_serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
                _serialPort.NewLine = "\n";
                //serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 9;
                //serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
                //serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                //_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
                //_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

                if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    _serialPort.Close();
                }
                _serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbText.InvokeRequired)
            {
                tbText.Invoke(new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived), sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("data: " + data);
                    tbText.Text = data;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error: " + ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }
```

It's seem the data is not read by line..

Comment: may be there is a `\n` (new line character) after `FF`?! Have you tried to put a breakpoint in the line: `string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();` what value does it have in the debugger? Also have you tried using `_serialPort.ReadExisting` ?

Comment: Hi, ReadExisting return only F. I check to see that no \n after FF, because if there have \n, then next printing data will contain ZZ.

Comment: how big is the `_serialPort.ReadBufferSize` ?

Comment: i checked buffer size is 4096

Comment: You should not be using ReadLine() method inside a receive event.  Use ReadBytes().

Comment: Hi can you explain your answer @ldweng

Comment: You are reading strings from the port.  But the device is not sending strings, it sends binary data.  You can tell from the display, serial device never know anything about Euros and Guilders.  You must use Read() instead.  Do not ignore its return value, you have to count-off the bytes you receive until you have a full response.  And do look in the manual or use a telephone so you understand what those byte values represent.